# Managing UI state in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a React application using Redux , for now there are 3 reducers - Event , Attendee , Locations. We have actions to add / modify / delete all the 3 reducers.

So far so good.

Now the problem is , I have many UI state like - showAddEventPopup, ShowEditEventPopup , isEventAddingSpinner, isEditingSpinner and many more. I would need to create actions for manipulating all these flags as many of them are based off redux-thunk result. ie: Show spinner when request sent , toggle isError when error received from server ... etc

I am sure there is a some elegant way to handle this ?

Comment: Just create another reducer - `uiFlags` - that is keyed by flag name. Dispatch your actions, consume in your reducers, and use selectors to show the spinnies.

Comment: but again I would end with many actions like - showAddEventPopup, ShowEditEventPopup , isEventAddingSpinner, isEditingSpinner ...

Comment: Not if you have one action that dispatches `{type: 'setUIFlag', payload 'showAddEventPopup'}`, and just return the new state with just the property in the payload modified.

Comment: Ah got it, and i would have all the states in the reducers - showAddEventPopup, ShowEditEventPopup , isEventAddingSpinner, isEditingSpinner ...  which would be manipulated by the reducer and i can map it in components

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you could have state that looks like:

```
store = {
    event: <state>
    attendee: <state>
    locations: <state>,
    uiFlags: {
        showAddEventPopup: false,
        showEditEventPopup: false,
        isEventAddingSpinner: false,
        isEditingSpinner: false
   }
}
```

With a `uiFlags` reducer like:

```
const getDefaultState => ({
    showAddEventPopup: false,
    showEditEventPopup: false,
    isEventAddingSpinner: false,
    isEditingSpinner: false
});

export const ACTION = {
    ENABLE_FLAG: 'enableUiFlag'
    DISABLE_FLAG: 'disableUiFlag',
    TOGGLE_FLAG: 'toggleUiFlag',
    RESET_ALL_FLAGS: 'resetUiFlags'
}

const reducer (state = getDefaultState(), action = {}) => {
    const {type, payload} = action;

    if (!payload) return state;      

    switch(type) {
        case ACTION.ENABLE_FLAG: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [payload]: true
            }
        }
        case ACTION.DISABLE_FLAG: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [payload]: false
            }
        }
        case ACTION.TOGGLE_FLAG: {
            return {
                ...state,
                [payload]: !state[payload]
            }
        }
        case ACTION.RESET_ALL_FLAGS: {
            return getDefaultState();
        }
        default: {
            return state;
        } 
    }
}
```

With thunks like:

```
import {ACTIONS} from './ui-flag-reducer'

function enableUiFlag(flagType) {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch({
        type: ACTION.ENABLE_FLAG,
        payload: 'showEditEventPopup'
    })
  };
}
```